# Excel Macro Change Cell Format to Text Of Protected Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a requirement to change a protected sheet cell format to Text(from Date) as soon as the sheet is opened. I mean to say the value should appear as it was entered into the sheet.

I have kept my code in Workbook_Open() event of ThisWorkBook, and the sequence of steps given below.

**Unprotect the Sheet:** `gSampleSheet.Unprotect Password:="MyPassword"`

**Change the Cell format:** `gSampleSheet.Range("K1:K100").NumberFormat = "Text"`

**Protect the Sheet:** `gSampleSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="MyPassword"`

When a Date value is entered in the cell then it should be converted to Text format and the value should appear as is.

i.e. If 12/12/15, 12.12.15, 12-12-15, 12-Dec-15 are entered then they should appear as they are entered(instead of changed to Date Format).

However the cell is showing some random values like T2015tx or some other values. Please help me to fix this as I am struggling to find out the root cause.

Comment: when you say that the value should appear as entered, do you mean you want to see it literally as it was written (12/12/15 or 12.12.15 or 12-12-15 or 12-Dec-15), or do you want the numerical representation to appear 42354 for example?

Comment: I wanted to show literally as it was written and fortunately i am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gSampleSheet.Range("K1:K100").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: While this is the correct syntax to get true text format, it will not keep the date as entered, but rather turn the date into its numerical equivalent in Excel.

Comment: Well, if the format is applied before the date is entered the conversion to date will not happen and the text won't change.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I was going to suggest that to the OP, but I am waiting on his response to my comment so its clear exactly what he needs.